# Is there a way to request an internal API of a public website from Node fetch?

Tags: node.js, http, request, fetch

I am trying to scrape dynamic websites and was using Puppeteer with Node.js before I realized i can just fetch the website's API directly and not have to render stuff that I don't need. By looking in the "Network" tab of Chrome's developer tools I could find the exact endpoints that returns the data I need. It works for most of the sites I am trying to scrape, but for some, especially POST requests, the API returns a "403: Forbidden" error code.

The API returns a success if I do a fetch-request directly from the Chrome console. But as soon as I try from a different tab, Postman, or Node using node-fetch I get "403: Forbidden".

I have tried copying the exact headers that are sent naturally from the website, and I have tried explicitly setting the "origin" and "referer" headers to the website's address but to no avail.

Is this simply a security measure that is impossible to breach or is there a way to trick the API into thinking that the request is coming from their own website?

Comment: You're failing authentication (that's what 403 means). Find out how the API server expects authentication - cookies, authorization header, some secret proprietary header etc.

Comment: @slebetman I just don't know how to find that out. I've manually added all of the headers and cookies of the original request, but the only thing that works is if I do the request from the chrome console on the website.

Comment: You can find out by looking at the network tab